# is there any benefit to using a created FUNCTION over declaring a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, declare

I use the below to return last weeks fiscal week number

```
SELECT (
    SELECT
        CA.FISCALWEEK
    FROM 
        EUUKSQL01.DASHBOARD.DBO.CALENDAR CA
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) = CONVERT(DATE,CA.FULLDATE)   ) - 1
```

If i use it a lot within a query I DECLARE & SET it as @LW etc.

I also created it as FUNCTION,

Is there any benefit to using one method over the other ?

Comment: If you use a variable the database will only execute the query once, but if you create that query as a function and call it from many places, the database will execute it every time. this means that setting a local variable should have better performance.

Comment: The function makes the code reusable.

Comment: A view is the best choice -- it is reusable and gives good performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDF (user defined function) can have a negative impact on your query-speed. If you haven't set your MAXDOP (max degree of parallelism) to 1 the query with your UDF will prevent parallelism.

You can see it in your explain-plan and try what solution is the faster one.

On the other hand the re-use of the code and the easier debugging is nice in the UDF.

If you want to have both, you could write your own CLR wich contains the logic of the UDF.

The Test I made:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLW]()
RETURNS datetime 
AS 
BEGIN
RETURN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
END
GO

SELECT * 
FROM [TGR].[dbo].[LargeTable]
WHERE BookingDate = [dbo].[GetLW]()
GO

DECLARE @LW datetime = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())

SELECT * 
FROM [TGR].[dbo].[LargeTable]
WHERE BookingDate = @LW
GO
```

Explain Plan:

[image]

So if you are in a DWH/BI enviroment, maybe the variable is the better solution.

Regards
Tgr

Comment: This was very useful, i was able to do something similar, when i ran both together UDF cost just 12% relative to the batch

Answer (score 0):

Using GETDATE() yields non deterministic results. I recommend to use the result in a variable. In addition to gaining performance by unique calling, you will be protected from inconsistent results. Imagine what happens if you have a sequence of GETDATE calls at midnight between two tax weeks, some of them before and some after.